# How to parse multiple fields into one sub-object in GSON?

Tags: json, gson, deserialization, json-deserialization

I'm trying to parse some json data that looks like this:

```
{
  "store_name": "Coffee Co",
  "location": "New York",
  "supplier_name": "Cups Corps",
  "supplier_id": 12312521,
  "supplier_email": "cups@cups.net"
}
```

And here's my Java POJOs

```
class Store {
    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("store_name")
    String storeName;
    String location;
    Supplier supplier;
}

class Supplier {
    String id;
    String name;
    String email;
}

//Getters and setters omitted
```

The issue I'm having is that the fields for the `Supplier` are flattened directly into the `Store` record.  I tried adding a `TypeAdapter` to my `Gson` object for `Supplier` but it doesn't get triggered because there's no field named `supplier` on the incoming json object.  I also can't use an alternate name for `supplier` because it needs information from all three of the fields in order to be created.

What is the best way to parse this data so that the nested `Supplier` field can also be populated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is use a custom deserializer:

```java
class StoreDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Store> {

    @Override
    public Store deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext) throws JsonParseException {
        JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();

        Supplier supplier = new Supplier(
                jsonObject.get("supplier_id").getAsInt(),
                jsonObject.get("supplier_name").getAsString(),
                jsonObject.get("supplier_email").getAsString()
        );

        return new Store(
                jsonObject.get("store_name").getAsString(),
                jsonObject.get("location").getAsString(),
                supplier
        );
    }
}
```

You can then deserialize by registering the deserializer:

```java
String json = "{\"store_name\":\"Coffee Co\",\"location\":\"New York\",\"supplier_name\":\"Cups Corps\",\"supplier_id\":12312521,\"supplier_email\":\"cups@cups.net\"}";
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Store.class, new StoreDeserializer()).create();
Store store = gson.fromJson(json, Store.class);
```

---

Note that I changed the type of `Supplier#id` to `int`, since it is numeric in your JSON:

```java
class Supplier {
    int id;
    String name, email;

    Supplier(int id, String name, String email) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

```java
class Store {
    String storeName, location;
    Supplier supplier;

    Store(String storeName, String location, Supplier supplier) {
        this.storeName = storeName;
        this.location = location;
        this.supplier = supplier;
    }
}
```